# Best way to transpose a datatable of id / field / value to a table with those fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data with this format:

```
ID | Header | Value

 1    Name    Jim
 1    Age     34
 1   Gender    M

 2    Name   Gibby
 2    Age     32
 2   Gender    F

 3    Name    Bob
 3    Age     100
 3   Gender    U
```

and I need to get it into another SQL db that has the fields listed in the `Header` column:

```
ID | Name | Age | Gender
1    Jim    34      M
2    Gill   32      F
3    Bob    100     U
```

I thought this was achievable with the PIVOT keyword:

```
select * FROM
    (SELECT [Id], [Header], [Value] FROM [Test].[dbo].[PivotTest]) src
PIVOT
    (count(Id) for [Header] in ([Name],[Age],[Gender])) piv
```

but have realised that aggregate functions are all about summing, counting etc.

Is this possible without doing a loop in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably doable using `pivot`, but the aggregation would be:

```
select id,
       max(case when header = 'Name' then Value end) as name,
       max(case when header = 'Age' then Value end) as Age,
       max(case when header = 'Gender' then Value end) as Gender
from pivottest
group by id;
```

One advantage of using conditional aggregation is that you can easily modify it to adjust the types:

```
select id,
       max(case when header = 'Name' then Value end) as name,
       try_convert(int, max(case when header = 'Age' then Value end)) as Age,
       max(case when header = 'Gender' then Value end) as Gender
from pivottest
group by id;
```

Comment: Ooh, that looks pretty straight-forward. In reality I have a lot more column headers (about 40) but only a few thousand rows - I'm guessing performance won't be too bad? I'll try it and see, thanks!

Comment: p.s. I edited your answer, it wouldn't compile, I had to change the column to [Value] as the result instead of the header name - but it works great.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Server Common Table Expression feature can be used to project virtual tables that you can rejoin:

```
WITH Name_CTE (ID, Value) AS
(
    SELECT ID, Value FROM PivotTest WHERE Header = 'Name'
),
Age_CTE (ID, Value) AS
(
    SELECT ID, Value FROM PivotTest WHERE Header = 'Age'
),
Gender_CTE (ID, Value) AS
(
    SELECT ID, Value FROM PivotTest WHERE Header = 'Gender'
)
SELECT Name_CTE.Value AS Name
,      Age_CTE.Value AS Age
,      Gender_CTE.Value AS Gender
FROM   Name_CTE
JOIN   Age_CTE ON Name_CTE.ID = Age_CTE.ID
JOIN   Gender_CTE ON Name_CTE.ID = Gender_CTE.ID
```

Note that this may not be the most performant approach if you're working on a large data set, but it does create a normalized view of the data

Answer (score 1):

```
    INSERT INTO @Table  VALUES
                            (1, 'Name'  , 'Jim'     )
                        ,   (1, 'Age'   , '34'      )
                        ,   (1, 'Gender', 'M'       )

                        ,   (2, 'Name'  , 'Gibby'   )
                        ,   (2, 'Age'   , '32'      )
                        ,   (2, 'Gender', 'F'       )

                        ,   (3, 'Name'  , 'Bob'     )
                        ,   (3, 'Age'   , '100'     )
                        ,   (3, 'Gender', 'U'       )
;

-- Insert next SELECT into your Table. Do the converts needed (i.e. Age)

SELECT  DISTINCT

            ID      =   TI.ID
        ,   Name    =   TN.Value
        ,   Age     =   TA.Value
        ,   Gender  =   TG.Value

FROM        @Table      TI
    JOIN    @Table      TN  ON  TN.ID = TI.ID   AND TN.Header = 'Name'
    JOIN    @Table      TA  ON  TA.ID = TI.ID   AND TA.Header = 'Age'
    JOIN    @Table      TG  ON  TG.ID = TI.ID   AND TG.Header = 'Gender'
```

Comment: That could work but I think because in reality I have 40 or so columns it might end up a little bloated

Comment: Create a Temp Table with all the fields. Insert just the unique IDs, rest of the fields NULL. Then do the updates field by field, based on the Header name. Same as the select, but just only single field update and a single join.